# why is my test skipped on jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this test using jest, but the second method is getting skipped, why?

```
const stringToTest = JSON.stringify({"filename":"9F6148567F8.jpg","id":"ss9:blob-ref:29e4b813a","diskp":"gotchi","mikoId":"e3f813a","content":"gotchi, 18/08/13 at 11:57 AM"});
```

describe('regex for uri', () => {

```
it('should match expected URI', () => {
    expect(matchUriRE.test(stringToTest)).toBe(true);
});

//below method skipped why?
it('should not be bull or undefined'), () => {
    expect(matchUriRE.test(stringToTest)).not.toBeNull;
    expect(matchUriRE.test(stringToTest)).not.toBe(null);
    expect(matchUriRE.test(stringToTest)).not.toBeUndefined();
};
})
```

with result:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 1 passed, 2 total
```

Comment: You’re not calling `expect(matchUriRE.test(stringToTest)).not.toBeNull`. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: Your "callback" is *outside* the call to `it`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple typo. Remove parenthesis after the test description and place it after closing `}` on the test.

```
it('should not be bull or undefined'), () => {
```

Should be

```
it('should not be bull or undefined', () => {
```

Answer (score 4):

it's not the case here but just for future reference in my case it was because i added only tag by mistake

exp:

```
it.only("test name", () => {})
```

this will only run this tests and ignore the other tests in the same file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33821529)

Answer (score -1):

I guess your test might get skipped if you are using a regex pattern that is faulty. Try stopping the tests and running it again.

Comment: Be careful not to make guesses on things without a solution. Make sure you put effort into finding a solution and not just making comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).